# Does a "vegan leather" exist?

Tags: veganism, substitutes, clothing, leather

Since I still have leather shoes, and since I will certainly need new shoes later for my work days, does a "vegan leather" exist?

As my work requires some presentation efforts, it would be great to have something visually similar or at least close to leather.

Comment: You're looking for a dress shoe, as opposed to a work boot or other heavy-duty "leather"?

Comment: @Erica Yes. Kind of shoes you can wear with a suit. My current ones are sneakers. But I would be interested for others too.

Comment: Two non-vegan but better options: buy used or recycled, and maintain carefully, including do not wear when not necessary.

Comment: There are many faux leathers, mimicking many types of leather.  I'm not sure this is specific enough to help anyone, or that it would still be about veganism if it were narrowed down.

Comment: @MatthewRead I disagree. I think many people can be interested in an alternative to leather. And how "vegan leather" is not specific?

Comment: Still hoping the "vans with a dress" trend will really catch on :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the [artificial leather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_leather) or alternative leather. The material is usually some kind of plastic.

There are even vegetable based alternatives, as indicated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_leather#Vegetable-based_alternatives).

Answer (score 7):

Yes. There is a type of [leather which is made out of Mushrooms](https://www.google.com/search?q=mushroom%20leather) and its products are trending. "**MuSkin**" is one of the popular brands of Mushroom Leather.