# Are there any vegan leathers suitable for tooling?

Tags: veganism, leather

Before going vegan, I appreciated the art of tooled leather. I'm curious whether there are any vegan leathers that are suitable to be used for tooling? I'd also be curious to learn about any artists doing it.

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/durable-trekking-boots-vegan

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/what-material-should-i-look-for-if-i-want-a-durable-comfortable-vegan-shoe/1941#1941

Comment: See also https://www.mercedes-market.com/2017/12/27/mb-tex-interior-mercedes-benz-interior-materials-explained/

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/71/does-a-vegan-leather-exist